# How to verify whether a postgresql database backup is performed

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to figure out a Way to check that after backing up a PostgreSQL database, does it produce some logs regarding the backup performed.

My intention as a postgresql db admin is, when the development teams backups the database from a remote server using any pgadmin tool, i need to know that a backup of database is taken with timestamp details. Is there some option to figure this out.

Awaiting for your valuable help.

Thanks
Yogi B

Comment: backups do not write to the database.

Answer (score 0):

pg-admin uses pg_dump to perform the backup (so does pg_dumpall etc)

Pg_dump uses SQL queries to retrieve the data, if you're got 
logging turned up high enough you might see something.

you will see evidence that a backup was attempted, but probably not an indication of success.

but this doesn't seem very practical.  you chould probably look for another way to solve whatever the real problem is..

Comment: Hi Jasen, Tried the same by enabling all log parameters for the database user, and could see the log file getting populated with a lot of querries.

Comment: but i was not able to know that a backup was tried by reading those logs. Is there any way to stop logging by deleting the pg_dump or pg_dumpall files from  the installation folder.

Comment: turn up logging higher. 'log_min_duration_statement = 0' etc. set log format to include application name.